# Get DataTime DataColumn of DataTable to List

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable, datacolumn

I want to get a DataColumn (of DataTime type) of my DataTable in List. How can I do this with LINQ?

I tried the following lines but didn't work:

```
DateTimeList = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
   .Where(dc => dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList());
```

DateTime values are created like the follow one:

```
new DateTime(2019, 6, 17, 16, 46, 05)
```

Comment: "*...didn't work*" is a vague description. What is the actual result and the expected result?

Comment: Other than the syntax error, that code does what it says you want it to do.

Comment: you want to get all columns that have type datetime or you want to get values?

Comment: I have a DataTable that have one DataColumn with DataTime type values. I want those values in a list. The problem with that code is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <System.Data.DataColumn>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List <System.DateTime>' ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a `List<DateTime>` type from the `DateTime` columns in a `DataTable`:

```cs
var dates = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    .SelectMany(c => c.Table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>(c.ColumnName))).ToList();
```

The query gets all the `DateTime` values whether the `dt` contains one or more `Column<DateTime>` type.

If you have a single `DataColumn<DateTime>` type in the table, you can write instead:

```cs
var dates = dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>(dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))?.ColumnName)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the code I was looking for! I was missing the SelectMany method. Can you explain why doesn't work directly with Select? 
DateTimeList = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .Where(dc => dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                        .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>(dc.ColumnName)).ToList();

Comment: There is any more efective way to do it if the DataTable have only one DataTime DataColumn?

Comment: @Queeng4 No problem how many DateTime columns, If you have just one, it will get it's values. If have more than one and you want to get the values of a specific column, then you need to specify that in a `.where` extension.

Comment: The code in my first comment have an error in the line ".Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>(dc.ColumnName)).ToList();". Doesn't recognize what is "dc".

Comment: @Queeng4 Your code doesn't work buddy. You need to get the values from the `Rows` collection and not from the `Columns` collection. Both `dc` variables are of `DataColumn` type. That's why I edited my answer to clarify that for you.